# vb Could I make this script shorter?

Tags: vb.net

I have a really long script fix but i'm wondering if I could make it shorter.

```
if year = 1894 Or year = 1895 Or year = 1896 Or year = 1897 Or year = 1898 Or year = 1899 Then fn1894()   
If year = 1900 Or year = 1901 Or year = 1902 Or year = 1903 Or year = 1904 Or year = 1905 Or year = 1906 Or year = 1907 Or year = 1908 Or year = 1909 Then fn1900()
```

Comment: This of course isn't all of it.

Comment: is this vbscript, or vba?  why the VB.NET tag?  there are much shorter ways for .Net

Comment: Vb.net. Hello again Btw you just helped me with an exception handling problem!

Comment: If the years are contiguous you could say `if year >= 1894 and year <= 1899 then fn1894()`

Comment: Is "year" of type "Integer"?

Comment: yes it is an integer entered by the user.

Comment: Entered by the user? In a textbox? Then are you converting it?

Comment: The problem is solved before I had If year >= 1900 OR year <= 1909 Then fn1900() and OR wouldn't work with multiple if's I didnt even think of AND.

Comment: Use "AndAlso", it is the better way for handling such things. And please answer on my question before.

Comment: It is a console application so no textbox's. They enter an integer though so what do you mean by convert?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I don't know why I got the down arrows I am just a beginner. Anyways the answers were still helpful! I would give them both a thumbs up but I went from 15 rep to 10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the years are adjacent, try this:

```
If year >= 1894 And year <= 1899 Then fn1894()   
If year >= 1900 And year <= 1909 Then fn1900()
```

Comment: Is your script really in VB.NET? In VB.NET this will work 100%

Comment: Yep, this is 100% right. Define "that doesn't work".

Comment: If neither of those methods are being called, perhaps your value isn't what you think it is, @user3439015

Comment: For some reason when I first tried this it didn't work at all. It seems to work as of now. This is how my script was before I added all those or's.

Comment: @Steve: The question is about making the code shorter. So I assume that the original works.

Comment: And what is the difference? Oo

Comment: OH I get why it didnt work the code before was If year >- 1894 or year <= 1899 then fn1894() ok thanks.

Comment: You say the user enters the input (I think in a textbox), are you converting it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
If year >= 1894 AndAlso year <= 1899 Then fn1984()
```

Same for the script after it. You should think of good method-names by the way, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select Case True
        Case iYear >= 1894 AndAlso iYear <= 1899
            'fn1894()
        Case iYear >= 1900 AndAlso iYear <= 1909
            'fn1900()
        Case Else
            ' else
    End Select
```